# Can't Install Package "sp"

Tags: r, mapping, geospatial, r-sp, install.packages

I am new to geospatial analysis in R as all of my previous experience is in bioinformatics work. I am attempting to install some of the basic geospatial packages, but am having some issues, specifically revolving around installing the package "sp". When attempt I `install.packages("sp")` I get the following result:

```
install.packages("sp")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/LMetz/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/sp_1.4-7.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/sp_1.4-7.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/sp_1.4-7.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘sp’ failed
```

It appears that the URL install.packages is trying to access to download the package no longer exists. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Check the firewall and/or network policies of your personal computer, your home network, your VPN, or your company/enterprise network. This error is from R but has nothing to do with R.

Comment: can you also try and install package `sf` ( `install.packages("sf")`)  ? As `sf` is the successor to `sp`.

Comment: I had no issues installing the "sf" package, but when I try to install packages such as "ggmap" or "tmap", I get error messages related to not having "sp" installed. So it appears that without sp I am limited on some of the other mapping packages I can access. This is why I would like to install sp, but of course I'm unable to.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the error "there is something wrong with downloading 'sf'". I searched the code and the following worked well:

```
install.packages("sp", dependencies = TRUE)
```